# Get everything between two spaces including a word stem

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract the filename from the following string:

```
s = '[download] /tmp/743979_file.mp4 has already been downloaded'
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
>>> re.search(r'(\s).+_file[^\s]+', s).group()
' /tmp/743979_file.mp4'
```

How would I get everything after the first space, before the second space, and which includes the word `_file` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\S` to match any non-space character. So `\S*` would match zero or more non-space characters. `\s` is just an opposite of `\S` where `\s` matches any kind of space character and `\S` matches any kind of non-space character.

```
>>> s = '[download] /tmp/743979_file.mp4 has already been downloaded'
>>> re.search(r'(?<=\s)\S*_file\S*', s).group()
'/tmp/743979_file.mp4'
```

OR

simply,

```
>>> re.search(r'\S*_file\S*', s).group()
'/tmp/743979_file.mp4'
```

**OR**

```
>>> s = '[download] /tmp/743979_file.mp4 has already been downloaded'
>>> m = s.split()[1]
>>> if '_file' in m:
        print(m)


/tmp/743979_file.mp4
```

Comment: What is the difference between `\s` and `\S*` ?

Comment: `\s` is whitespace, `\S` is non-whitespace, and `*` means 0 or more of the preceding object.

Answer (score 2):

Another simple solution could be using `split`:

```
print '[download] /tmp/743979_file.mp4 has already been downloaded'.split()[1]
```